# iPhone UISearch AutoComplete Override With Custom Word Suggestions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autocomplete, uisearchbar

I am trying to control/override the auto-complete feature when a user enters text in my iPhone app.

Specifically I'd like to auto-complete a collection of words I supply. For example let's say a word in my list is Macpapajona. When I type "mac" auto-complete will suggest Macpapajona.

How can I do this?

I understand that I have to use this type of method, but what code would provide the replacement bubble?  A custom UIView?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"ma"])
   if (![string isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
     // code to pop up a subview that has the word "Macpapajona" in it.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to be a missing feature of the iPhone API. Even implementing it yourself seems like a pain in the butt since modifying the text in a UITextField without messing with the cursor position is itself not well supported. However, I think there is a solution. Check out the TTPickerTextField which is part of the free & open source [Three20 project](https://github.com/facebook/three20#readme). I'm about to start using it myself and will update this post with my reaction & possibly some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up populating a tableview with suggested words.